# A6 GSM Module | How to Play audio file with A6 mini GSM Module

Tags: gsm, at-command

I want to play an .amr file with A6 mini GSM Module.
In the datasheet of A6 GSM module it is noted that this module supports digital audio and analog audio, supports HR, FR, EFR, AMR voice coding.
I want to know if I can make a voice call using this module and play a pre-recorded audio file instead of plugging the microphone?
Can I store the audio file to the flash buffer of this module?

Is there an AT Command to do this?
How can I do this?